# Получение названия браузера через $_SERVER

Tags: php, сервер, браузер

используя $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']

в базу записываются значения :
 chrome - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.13

Edge - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.11

Вопрос: почему оба значения одинаковые ( кроме цифр).И если так и должно  быть как по цифрам браузер узнавать?

Сайт на опенсервере локальный

Comment: Как мне в бд записать верный браузер? Можно и не по стандарту , просто словом. Для анализа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Процитирую википедию:

> Когда Internet Explorer стал доминирующим браузером, такие конкуренты
>   как Firefox, Safari и Opera встроили системы, позволяющие пользователю
>   выбрать ложное значение User-Agent, такое же, что и у свежих версий
>   Explorer. Некоторые из них (Firefox и Safari) копировали значение
>   User-Agent полностью, другие (Opera) копировали значение User-Agent,
>   добавляя истинное имя браузера в конце, что позже привело к тому, что
>   строка содержит три имени и версии: первое зовётся как «Mozilla» (то
>   есть Netscape Navigator); далее «MSIE» (Internet Explorer); и
>   последнее, действительный браузер, такой как «Opera». Opera также
>   позволяла полностью замаскироваться под Internet Explorer или Firefox,
>   полностью скрывая имя «Opera».
>
> В случае Safari строка User-Agent содержит 5 имен (Mozilla,
>   AppleWebKit (идентификатор «движка»), «KHTML, like Gecko»
>   (используемый Safari WebKit основан на движке KHTML, Gecko — кодовое
>   имя движка последних версий Mozilla Firefox) и Safari. Таким образом,
>   если сайт делает проверку на практически любой современный браузер
>   (кроме Opera) — Safari её пройдет. Другие браузеры на движке WebKit
>   работают аналогично.
>
> Кроме браузеров, другие программы, использующие протокол HTTP, к
>   примеру менеджеры закачек и оффлайновые браузеры, также имеют
>   возможность изменять значение User-Agent, посылаемое серверу, по
>   желанию пользователя. Это сделано, наверное, для обеспечения
>   совместимости с определёнными серверами (некоторые серверы
>   отказываются обслуживать подобные программы, так как они могут оказать
>   значительные нагрузки на ресурсы сервера; Google, например, для
>   дефолтового юзерагента python urllib отдает 403).
>
> Подобная проблема продолжает существовать в мире браузеров, и поэтому
>   начата кампания, способствующая тому, чтобы разработчики сайтов
>   проектировали сайты в соответствии со стандартами, а не для какого-то
>   любого определённого браузера.
>
> Так, многие веб-сайты, созданные в 2005 году, лучше соответствуют
>   стандартам, чем это было ранее в истории Web. Однако, на некоторых
>   сайтах всё ещё используются устаревшие скрипты JavaScript, в сущности,
>   блокирующие работу других браузеров, помимо Internet Explorer или
>   Netscape Navigator. Причина этого часто заключается в бездумном
>   копировании старого кода, взятого с других сайтов, без полного
>   понимания того, какой эффект этот код будет в действительности иметь.

**Дополнение к ответу:**
В php предусмотрена функция get_browser

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\n\n";

$browser = get_browser(null, true);
print_r($browser);
?>
```

Ответ:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7) Gecko/20040803 Firefox/0.9.3

Array
(
    [browser_name_regex] => ^mozilla/5\.0 (windows; .; windows nt 5\.1; .*rv:.*) gecko/.* firefox/0\.9.*$
    [browser_name_pattern] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; ?; Windows NT 5.1; *rv:*) Gecko/* Firefox/0.9*
    [parent] => Firefox 0.9
    [platform] => WinXP
    [browser] => Firefox
    [version] => 0.9
    [majorver] => 0
    [minorver] => 9
    [cssversion] => 2
    [frames] => 1
    [iframes] => 1
    [tables] => 1
    [cookies] => 1
    [backgroundsounds] =>
    [vbscript] =>
    [javascript] => 1
    [javaapplets] => 1
    [activexcontrols] =>
    [cdf] =>
    [aol] =>
    [beta] => 1
    [win16] =>
    [crawler] =>
    [stripper] =>
    [wap] =>
    [netclr] =>
)
```

**Но будьте внимательны**, функция работает при определенных условиях, о которых можете прочитать здесь: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.get-browser.php

Также есть такое решение https://github.com/ThaDafinser/UserAgentParser Я использую именно это.

Comment: Спасибо , перефразирую немного вопрос. Как мне в бд записать верный браузер? Можно и не по стандарту , просто словом. Для анализа.

Comment: @АлександрЖарков дополнил ответ

Comment: Спасибо, человек.